# how to tell if browser is done rendering the visible area of page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger some effect and i want it to start when browser is done rendering the visible part...so as soon as everything that is visible rendered. But sooner, when things are being drawn and realigning, and not after a mile long page is loaded.

If this requires restructuring page then so be it.

Comment: is the visible part your entire browser window?

Comment: i guess `window.onload` will be fine

Comment: use `$('selector').load(function(){})`

Comment: Is the page rendered from static HTML structure or are you adding content dynamically?

Comment: i want code to know if things are going to be loaded dynamically or static or at least of have an option to configure the script